# Passing data from HTML service to Google Sheet not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an HTML sidebar that I have coded with Google Apps Script (linked to a Google Sheet) with draggable / droppable divs. The idea is, the use changes the position of the divs and then clicks submit, and the contents of those divs are then printed in the right order in certain target cells in my Google Sheet.

The only way I have found to pass this data to the server when the button is clicked is to use the 'name' attribute in a text input, and so I have therefore created a series of empty text inputs (which I will later hide) which auto-populate with the values of the divs within the correct order. Here is my HTML:

```
<form id = "sortable" class="ui-state">

             <div class = "sortableItem day">Monday</div>

              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result1"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result2"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result3"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result4"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result5"></div>

             <div class = "sortableItem day">Tuesday</div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result6"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result7"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result8"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result9"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result10"></div>

             <div class = "sortableItem day">Wednesday</div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result11"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result12"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result13"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result14"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result15"></div>

             <div class = "sortableItem day">Thursday</div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result16"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result17"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="dresult18"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result19"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result20"></div>

             <div class = "sortableItem day">Friday</div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result21"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result22"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result23"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result24"></div>
              <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="result25"></div>

       <div>  

              <!-- hidden text inputs to record hotel order for pulling through to server using 'name' attribute (can't be used on divs) -->       

              <input type="text" id="meeting1" name="meeting1">
              <input type="text" id="meeting2" name="meeting2">
              <input type="text" id="meeting3" name="meeting3">
              <input type="text" id="meeting4" name="meeting4">
              <input type="text" id="meeting5" name="meeting5">
              <input type="text" id="meeting6" name="meeting6">
              <input type="text" id="meeting7" name="meeting7">
              <input type="text" id="meeting8" name="meeting8">
              <input type="text" id="meeting9" name="meeting9">
              <input type="text" id="meeting10" name="meeting10">
              <input type="text" id="meeting11" name="meeting11">
              <input type="text" id="meeting12" name="meeting12">
              <input type="text" id="meeting13" name="meeting13">
              <input type="text" id="meeting14" name="meeting14">
              <input type="text" id="meeting15" name="meeting15">
              <input type="text" id="meeting16" name="meeting16">
              <input type="text" id="meeting17" name="meeting17">
              <input type="text" id="meeting18" name="meeting18">
              <input type="text" id="meeting19" name="meeting19">
              <input type="text" id="meeting20" name="meeting10">
              <input type="text" id="meeting21" name="meeting21">
              <input type="text" id="meeting22" name="meeting22">
              <input type="text" id="meeting23" name="meeting23">
              <input type="text" id="meeting24" name="meeting24">
              <input type="text" id="meeting25" name="meeting25">

          </div>

          <!-- submit button : hidden until check box checked -->

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg center-block" id="click">

          <!-- checkbox - user confirms they are happy with order + triggers function to update text inputs with new hotel order -->

          <em>Click to confirm you are happy with the new order </em><input type="checkbox" id="check">

          </form>
```

This is the script that populates the empty text inputs when checkbox is checked:

```
var textInputArray = [];

       $("#check").click(function() {

        for(var i = 0; i<=25; i++) {

       // update array with new hotel order

        textInputArray.push(sortable.children[i].innerHTML);

        $("#meeting" + i).val(textInputArray[i]);
        }
       })
```

So far so good! I then added this within the script in my HTML doc:

```
   window.onload = function() {

      document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
        .addEventListener('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); 
          google.script.run.handleFormSubmit(this);  
          google.script.host.close();

        });
   }
```

And in my .gs file:

```
function handleFormSubmit(form) {

  var test = form.meeting1;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D25').setValue(test);
}
```

(at the moment I have only got as far as populating the first entry whilst I test).

Now this works - but very intermittently. I works, then I run it again and it doesn't, and then it seems sometimes I go back to it and it works again! It is extremely unstable so I imagine there is something very wrong with the script here. So a couple of thing:

1- what are the errors in my current script

2- I imagine there is a far better way to pull through the data from my divs without the 'fake' hidden text boxes... but cannot find any alternative right now as seems I need the 'name' attribute?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems that the values from "meeting1" to "meeting25" can be retrieved and can be sent to GAS side. I couldn't understand the situation of your issue. So can I ask you about the output you want? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Your English is great! Essentially when I click on submit, the value of the text input (meeting1) should populate cell D25. And it does sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't. If you like, I could share the google doc with you as it's quite difficult to explain!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your concern. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, in order to run ``google.script.host.close()`` after ``handleFormSubmit(this)``, how about modifying to ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {google.script.host.close()}).handleFormSubmit(this)``? If this didn't work yet, I would like to think of other solutions.

Comment: this works great! Perfect! I may need a little help from you again at some point ;)

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. google.script.run is the asynchronous work. So in your script, ``handleFormSubmit()`` of ``google.script.run.handleFormSubmit(this)`` is run while ``google.script.host.close()`` is run. For this situation, I thought that after ``handleFormSubmit()`` was run, running ``host.close()`` might become one of solutions. Reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).